# Checking whether two voltages are similar

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, low-power, comparator

I am pretty new to electronics so this may seem like a basic question, but how could I check whether two voltages are similar? For example, say I want to check whether | V1 - V2 | < 1.5V and output either Vcc ( true ) or Gnd ( false ) accordingly.

1.5V is just a figure. It doesn't need to be a very specific value. Instead, I should be able to tune it with a potentiometer or by choosing different resistors.

Low power is definitely a bonus.

I already have a few LM324's ( op amp ) which I think could be helpful.

Comment: The function is called a *window comparator*. AFAIK it's normally built from two comparators and an AND or OR gate. If you use open-drain comparators, you can get the AND function for free.

Comment: I am guessing two comparators are needed to check that V1 is in (V2-1.5,V2) and (V2,V2+1.5), right? Also, the open-drain is to build a wired AND based on high impedance pins, correct? Finally, can this be done with a LM324?

Comment: I'd recommend using a comparator designed as a comparator rather than an op-amp, although many op-amps can be used as comparators. LM293 is an example of a cheap dual comparator that might work.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually talking about performing three functions: subtraction (or difference), absolute value, and comparison with a fixed value. For determining the difference between the two input values you need a *differential amplifier*. There are a number of such circuits that use an operational amplifier, and the proper choice may depend on the source impedance of V1 and V2. If these inputs have a low impedance you may be able to use just one op amp to compute the difference, and in the worst case scenario you would need three op amps. The absolute value can be computed using one op amp and a couple of diodes configured as a *precision rectifier*. Finally, you need a standard comparator where the trip voltage is set by a ratio of fixed resistors or a potentiometer.

I don't think the LM324 is a particularly low power op amp, and it's not clear what you even mean by the phrase "low power", so I'll leave that issue for another question.

Comment: I am trying to keep this below 5mA. I searched the internet and found that the LM324 consumes less than 1mA. That seems quite acceptable to me. I think it does indeed make sense to split the problem in three like you said but I wanted to know if there was a simpler way to do it given the number of possibilities these devices offer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to build a differential amplifier and a window comparator.  The signal coming out of the differential amplifier will be proportional to the difference between the two input voltages.  Then all you need to do is add two comparators and two reference voltages.  The reference voltages should be symmetrical around your ground reference.  The comparators can then be used to determine if the voltage from the amplifier is between the reference voltages or not.  You can get comparators with open drain outputs, and these outputs can be directly connected in parallel, forming a wired AND gate.  All you need is a pull-up resistor.  All you would need to do is configure the comparators so one of them will pull the output low when the input voltage is above the upper limit, and the other one will pull the output low when the input voltage is below the lower limit.  Need adjustable limits?  Just add a pot between the differential amplifier and the comparators.